Can I impose an inflation floor for a VAR model?
I am trying to forecast inflation using a VAR. After Granger causality and carefully analyzing impulse response functions, I have selected three variables to include in the VAR. My issue is that while test set prediction accuracy is great, the forecast continues the downward trend observed until it's negative. Now, I know that inflation cannot be less than 0. Is there a sophisticated way to ensure that my inflation forecast will stay around or above 3%, which is more realistic?

Bayesian VAR with a prior?

@Durden, that can help restrict the estimates of the parameter values to fall in a desired range, but would that help restrict the values of the time series as the OP wishes? If anything, I think it would be the likelihood rather than the prior that could do that. Anyway, if we were to stick to frequentist analysis, my idea would be to include some form of nonlinearity in the model. E g. when inflation gets below some threshold, a mechanism kicks in to pull it up. There could be a hard threshold or a smooth form of nonlinearity.

I think it might require a combination of a restricted likelihood function and prior.

@RichardHardy i had done a log transform that kept the desired value above 3 but i was hoping for a more sophisticated way. can you expand on what a smooth form of nonlinearity would be?

The closer you get to the limit, the stronger the pull in the opposite direction, and this in a smooth way. E.g. if the lower limit is $\ell$ and the variable is $x$ where $x>0$, there is an additive term of $\frac{c}{x-\ell}x$ with $c<0$. Not saying this is the best, just a possible example.
